# Code before synchronous AJAX call freezes in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I want to change a button to a loading state when a synchronous AJAX call is being executed. Except the jQuery code (in Chrome) that change the button to loading state freezes until the AJAX call is finished. So the loading state will show up for maybe 1 ms after de ajax call.

I created an example in JSFiddle to check it out. *(Check in Chrome)*
http://jsfiddle.net/b8w9hf01/

```
$('.button').on('click', function()
{
    // change button text (DOESN'T SHOW)
    $(this).html('Loading..').delay(10);

    // do async call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/insert-key-here/insert-value-here/key/value',
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(poResponse){
            console.log(poResponse);
        }
    });

    // change button text
    $('.button').html('Done');

    // put Click here back after a second, for repeation of the test
    setTimeout(function() { $('.button').html('Click here'); }, 1000);
});
```

**Changing it to an async call would work, but will be to much work for now.** Does anyone has an solution? Thanks!

Comment: `async:false` will block javascript execution till the `ajax` call is complete. The behaviour is correct.

Comment: I understand, but the first change is before the ajax call?

Comment: See my answer, for the expected behaviour you wish for the button :)

Comment: I think @pascalvgemert means the ajax request is executed too quickly after the button is clicked and therefore you don't see the `Loading` text

Comment: Your `delay()` call does nothing unless you call a queued item on the same object. What you should do is put the whole `$.ajax` in another `setTimeout` with a short interval. That'll give the UI a moment to update..

Comment: But `setTimeout` is also async :D

Comment: @iceless that is true, but in my situation it's a workaround. Thanks @cookie-monster!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the explanation, you can check [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7464):

> The code before the call is running, but that doesn't mean you will
>   see the result immediately. If the call is truly and completely
>   synchronous, the window update might not happen until after the $.ajax
>   call completes.

If you insist on using a synchronous ajax call, which is really deprecated, you can do the following:

```
// change button text
$(this).html('Loading..');

// do async call
setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/insert-key-here/insert-value-here/key/value',
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (poResponse) {
            console.log(poResponse);
        }
    });
    // change button text
    $('.button').html('Done');
}, 20);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8w9hf01/6/)

**Update**

For the record, the async version is really simple here:

```
// change button text
$(this).html('Loading..');

// do async call
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/insert-key-here/insert-value-here/key/value',
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (poResponse) {
        // change button text
        $('.button').html('Done');
        console.log(poResponse);
    }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8w9hf01/7/)

Comment: I know async is easy, but to rewrite over 30 sync calls to async takes a while.

Comment: @pascalvgemert You'd better get started then :)

Comment: I didn't know that the async=true or false could help me show the loader on chrome and IE. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the code which will create the expected behaviour, u wanted out of your button:

```
$('.button').on('click', function()
{
// change button text (DOESN'T SHOW)
$(this).html('Loading..');
// Let's disable the button to prevent further clicks.
$(this).('attr','disabled');

// do async call
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/insert-key-here/insert-value-here/key/value',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(poResponse){
        //Ajax is successful, we can enable the button again.
        setTimeout(function() { 
             $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
             $(this).html('Done');
        }, 1000);
    },
    error: function(){
        //So there was an error, let's enable the button & let the user know (so wise of us)
        setTimeout(function() { 
             $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
             $(this).html('Error occured, Try Again');
        }, 1000);
    }

});

// put Click here back after a second, for repeation of the test
setTimeout(function() { $('.button').html('Click here'); }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I know I can solve it with an async call, that was not the question. The question is, is there any other way with a sync call? I read something about JQuery.Deferrer for example.

Comment: Please enlighten us, as to why you wish to use a sync call? We can workaround the issue.

Comment: I already said that in the question: "Changing it to an async call would work, but will be to much work for now"