# Chrome only : ajax freezing my javascript execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ajax means asynchronous, but it seems like its stopping my javascript execution or at least pausing it and resuming on response.

HTML value

```
 <input value="foo" data-loading-text="bar" class="foo">
```

Extending jquery -->

```
$.fn.bootstrapButton= function(type){
    $el = $(this);
    loadingText = $el.attr("data-loading-text");
    currentValue = $el.val();
    if(type === "loading")
      $el.attr("data-loading-text",currentValue)
        .val(loadingText)
        .prop("disabled", true)
    else if( type === "reset")
      $el.val(loadingText)
        .prop("disabled", false)
        .attr("data-loading-text", currentValue)
}
```

Function call -->

```
save= function (name){
  $save = $(".ok")
  $save.bootstrapButton("loading")
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    url: '/server'
    cache: false
    dataType: 'json'
    data:"ss"
    success: function(response){
       alert("success")
    }).always(function(){
    $save.bootstrapButton("reset")
  })
}
```

I'm extending bootstrap's button coz of jquery UI's button problem. But -- when this is executing, I never see the loading text until ajax request is completed!! da faq!. Asynchronous isn't true asynchronous?

BTW, the code works without any glitch ( I can see the loading text ) with this small modification.

```
save= function (name){
  $save = $(".ok")
  $save.bootstrapButton("loading")
  setTimeout(funtion(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST'
      url: '/server'
      cache: false
      dataType: 'json'
      data:"ss"
      success: function(response){
         alert("success")
      }).always(function(){
      $save.bootstrapButton("reset")
    })
  },100)
}
```

i.e, with a 100 millisec delay, the loading text appears!, what gives?

Comment: I've noticed this happening with Chrome but not Firefox. Are you a Chrome developer?

Comment: is it by any chance possible that the 'async' option is set to false for those ajax calls ? jQuery ajax call supports a way to make the call synchronous. So if something set async to false this could explain it ... try setting it mannualy to true (async: true, ....). Just guessing here, sry I cant be more helpful

Comment: Alert has nothing to do with it.. yes, seen in chrome. havnt checked firefox

Comment: @Andy -- True that, only on chrome. Will update the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911736/solved-code-before-synchronous-ajax-call-freezes-in-chrome

Comment: You could pass it off to a webworker to do the ajax to keep the UI thread clean.

Comment: Only available >=IE10 FWIW.

Comment: the link helped @andy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below as an option in my ajax query solved the issue.

> async: true

Answer (score 2):

The construction:

```
$.ajax({
.... 
}).always(function(){
    $save.bootstrapButton("reset")
  })
```

says: "Execute this Ajax command, and when it is done always run this anonymous function.

So you've explicitly said, "wait until the Ajax call is done", and it's working.

Comment: loading text isnt seen @bobdye. Read my question again please.

Comment: He read it well. It won't be seen, The browser does not update the DOM at once, it waits until the JavaScript function returns.